# EC2 CloudWatch memory metrics don't match what Top shows

Tags: memory, memory-management, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a t2.micro EC2 instance, running at about 2% CPU. I know from other posts that the CPU usage shown in TOP is different to CPU reported in CloudWatch, and the CloudWatch value should be trusted.

However, I'm seeing very different values for Memory usage between TOP, CloudWatch, and NewRelic.

There's 1Gb of RAM on the instance, and TOP shows ~300Mb of Apache processes, plus ~100Mb of other processes. The overall memory usage reported by TOP is 800Mb. I guess there's 400Mb of OS/system overhead?

However, CloudWatch reports 700Mb of usage, and NewRelic reports 200Mb of usage (even though NewRelic reports 300Mb of Apache processes elsewhere, so I'm ignoring them).

The CloudWatch memory metric often goes over 80%, and I'd like to know what the actual value is, so I know when to scale if necessary, or how to reduce memory usage.

Here's the recent memory profile, seems something is using more memory over time (big dips are either Apache restart, or perhaps GC?)

[Screenshot of memory usage over last 12 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3tFt.png)

Answer (score 1):

AWS doesn't supports Memory metrics of any EC2 instance. As Amazon does all his monitoring from outside the EC2 instance(servers), it is unable to capture the memory metrics inside the instance. But, for complete monitoring of an instance, you must need Memory Utilisation statistics for any instance, along with his CPU Utilisation and Network IO operations.
But, we can use custom metrics feature of cloudwatch to send any app-level data to Cloudwatch and monitor it using amazon tools.
You can follow this blog for more details: http://upaang-saxena.strikingly.com/blog/adding-ec2-memory-metrics-to-aws-cloudwatch

You can set a cron for 5 min interval in that instance, and all the data points can be seen in Cloudwatch.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch doesn't actually provide metrics regarding memory usage for EC2 instance, you can confirm this [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ec2-metricscollected.html).

As a result, the MemoryUtilization metric that you are referring to is obviously a custom metric that is being pushed by something you have configured or some application running on your instance.

As a result, you need to determine what is actually pushing the data for this metric. The data source is obviously pushing the wrong thing, or is unreliable.

The behavior you are seeing is not a CloudWatch problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
To clarify, I'm using the scripts provided by Amazon to send memory information to Cloudwatch (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html)
Comparing this to memory information provided by Top and NewRelic shows different values, so I'm trying to understand which one to trust most when it comes to assessing when the server is reaching capacity.

Comment: That's really interesting. I'm not entirely sure how those scripts work, but I know they're not supported officially. Are you using Amazon Linux? Maybe the scriptalso s aren't as reliable with other Linux distros... I'd recommend that you put this on the official AWS support forums

Comment: Reference to "I know they're not supported official" - The OP gave  a link to AWS documents. So it is officially supported right ?